# Expo Camera Not Showing What Camera Sees

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use Expo's  component to create a QRCode scanner. It builds without a problem, but when I open it up it displays a blank box instead of whatever the camera sees.

I've tried using a variety of barcode scanner libraries/packages, including BarCodeScanner found here: https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner as well as Expo's own BarCodeScanner: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/

```
import{ Camera, Permissions, BarCodeScanner } from 'expo';

import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode';

    render() {
      return(
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.fieldBox}>
            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/images/profile_pic.jpg')}
              style={styles.profileImg}/>
            <View style={styles.nameBox}>
              <Text style={styles.baseText, styles.headerText}>{fullName}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.baseText, styles.headerText}>{userStatus}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.fieldBox}>
              <Text style={styles.baseText}>Bio</Text>
              <Text style={styles.baseText}>{bioText}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.fieldBox}>
            <Button
                onPress={onPressLearnMore}
                title="Learn More"
                color="#841584"
                accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
              />


             <SocialIcon
               title='Sign in with Facebook'
               button
               type='facebook'
             />
            <Button
            title="Logout"
            onPress={async () => {
                try {
                    await logout();
                }
                catch (e) {
                    Alert.alert(
                        "Failed to log out",
                        e.message,
                        [{ text: "Ok", onPress: () => { } }]
                    );
                    return;
                }
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
            }}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.QRCode}>
                <QRCode
                    value={"This is a test"}
                    bgColor='#000'
                    fgColor='#fff'
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.QRCode}>

            </View>
            <View>
            {this._maybeRenderAttendeeStatus()}
            </View>
            </View>
            </ScrollView>
    );
  }
  _maybeRenderAttendeeStatus() {
        var user_status = '';
            if(this.state.codeHasBeenScanned){
                if(this.state.isValidUser){
                    user_status = 'The person is registered';
                }
                else{
                    user_status = 'The person is not registered';
                }
            }
        if(this.state.userType == 'organizer'){
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>
                        {user_status}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
  }

  _maybeRenderQRCodeScanner = () => {
    console.log("Determining if I should render QR code scanner");
    if (this.state.userType == 'organizer') {
      console.log("User is an organizer");
      return (
        <BarCodeScanner

                  onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead}

        />
      );
    }
  }

  _handleBarCodeRead = ( { type, data }) => {
    this.setState({codeHasBeenScanned:true});
    console.log('barcode was recognized and scanned');
    if(true){//later need to change this to change behavior based on data
        this.setState({isValidUser:true});
    }
    else{
        this.setState({isValidUser:false});
    }

  }

}
```

I expect it to have some information, followed by a QR code and then a little box that shows what the camera is seeing. However instead I get just a blank box:

[Photo of what my app displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WEuq.png)

Comment: How do I close this question? I realized that I simply made a mistake and never actually called the function _maybeRenderQRCodeScanner() in the View I had allocated it for it.

Answer (score 0):

Expo only shows what your app build will look like to the user initially. It won't auto-read the QR code. You will have to scan the compiled QR code from the expo screen using another code reader to get the result of the scanned code in the box.

I scanned your generated code using your image using "Lightning QR Scanner", as I imagine you would expect a user to, and got the following result:

[image: expo qr scanned result (edited to remove google ad)]

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Rachel thanks for the reply, but I think you misunderstood my question (or, more likely, I didn't make my question clear enough). I do not expect the app to read the QR code on its own; rather, the box you see below the QR code is supposed to be a QR scanner that can scan other QR codes. It is generated using a library like react-native-barcodescanner or react-native-camera, and so it is supposed to show whatever the camera of the phone sees (after first asking for permission). However, it is currently not showing what the camera is supposed to see.